# Access denied (HTTP 403) from one computer but not from the other

Tags: windows, browser, http

Two computers on my home network, connected via ethernet cables to the same router (so same external IP).  One runs Win 8.1, the other Win 10.

I got sent a URL (an image from i.pinimg.com).  I can access it from one computer (Win 8.1) via different browsers, without any problem.  However, when I try to access that URL from the other computer (Win 10) I get a 403 permission denied response.

I tried two different browsers (Firefox 52ESR and IE 11), I tried creating fresh FF profiles, I tried copying the FF profiles between the computers, but nothing helps -- one computer is granted access but the other is not.

I'm at wits end.  Please advise.

Comment: Do you have any security software on the non-working machine? Does the image require a login to access, maybe there is a token saved on the working computer - try incognito mode on the working computer and see if it still works? Can you provide the link to the image for us to check?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently something decided to helpfully format a part of the URL.  A `--` was turned to `%E2%80%93`, which was displayed as a long dash in the address field.  Bleh!

I have no idea what caused it (Discord maybe?) but once I noticed the difference and used the correct url, everything worked just fine.

Apologies for wasting your time.